# Ken Sherriff Arduino Version Tv-Be-Gone

Tags: arduino-uno, remote-control

I am trying to make [Ken Sherriff's version](http://www.righto.com/2010/11/improved-arduino-tv-b-gone.html) of the TV-Be-Gone with the Arduino using the updated v1.2 software.  He uses this setup:

### His Setup

[image: Setup]

### My Setup

I used the Arduino Nano with same MCU (Atmel ATmega328) as Uno but changed a few other things also. For power I supplied 9v to the vin pin but supplied the transistor with 5v from the 5v pin. I used this [Instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-TV-B-Gone/) by the same person.  The only major change was I used a PN2222A transistor instead of 2N4401.

[image]

### Problem

My problem is that even though when I push the button the infrared light blinks for a while sending the different codes my receiver won't pick it up. I checked my receiver with other remotes and it works and I tried at close and far range. My receiver just blinks if it senses any infrared command regardless of what type of remote but it doesn't work with my Arduino TV-Be-Gone. I haven't tried it with a real TV yet but would like for it to work before I try it on a real one.